# Cannot call HttpGet method with parameters in C# .Net Framework

Tags: c#, http-get

I have a problem with calling a HttpGet method with parameters. I am working in .Net Framework 4.7.2. I am using Advanced REST Client to test my methods.
When I call a method with no parameters, it works just fine, but when I want to call a method with parameters I am not able to. Where is the mistake I am making?
Here are my 2 methods.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("action1")]
    public IHttpActionResult action1()
    {
        return Ok("blabla");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("action2/{parameter}")]
    public IHttpActionResult action2(string parameter)
    {
        return Ok(parameter);
    }
```

And here is how I call the second method. As I said, the first one works just fine.
[image: Advanced Rest client usage]

Here is the message I keep getting:`{ "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44338/api/login/action2/?parameter="blabla"'.", "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Login' that matches the request." }`

Comment: Try using URL `https://localhost:44338/api/login/action2/blabla`

Comment: Oh, thank you, it indeed does work. I thought I had tried it, but apparently only tried it with quotation marks

Comment: FYI - You don't need the quotation marks for strings in query parameters either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action is using a route parameter which magically matches parts of the url string (not query parameters) to the actions parameters.

You should either change the URL in Postman to `https://localhost:44338/api/login/action2/blabla`

or you could remove `{parameter}` from the Route Attribute